# Coin throw approximation

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem, binomial-distribution, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

We have coin and we want to determine the probability $p$, that this coin shows "head" after one throw. For this purpose the coin has been thrown $n$-times and $K_i$ is the event that in the $i$-th throw "head" has been thrown.

a) Why is

$\hat{p}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} 1_{K_i}$

($1_{K_i}$ is the indicator function) an approximation value for p? Justify this with the strong Law of large numbers.

b) Assuming the real value of p is 0.3 and the coin is thrown 100 times. Calculate

$\mathbb{P}(0.25\leq \hat{p} \leq 0.35)$

c) How many times must the coin be thrown, so that

$\mathbb{P}(0.25\leq \hat{p} \leq 0.35)\geq 0.95$ for $p=0.3$

d) How many times must the coin be thrown, so that

$\mathbb{P}(p-0.05\leq \hat{p} \leq p+0.05)\geq 0.95$ for all $p\in[0,1]$

Hint: Use the function values for the Quantile function $\Phi (1.09)=0.8621,\Phi ^{-1}(0.975)=1.96 $

So with a) i have no idea how to justify this, with b) i used the central limit theorem but i do not get any reasonable values to use with $\Phi (x)$. I assumed that this was a binomial distribution with mean $\mu =E(X_i)=n\times p=100\times 0.3=30$ and $\sigma ^2=Var(X_i)=n\times p(1-p)=21$. With these values i get

$\mathbb{P}(\frac{-2975}{\sqrt{21\times 100}} \leq \frac{X_1+...+X_{100}-30\times 100}{\sqrt{21\times 100}} \leq \frac{-2965}{\sqrt{21\times 100}})$

which does not bring me any further. c) and d) are then similar to b).

Comment: for (i) notice how that right hand expression is just adding up the total number of heads and dividing by the total number of trials.

Comment: Are you referring to task a)? This is something like the arithmetic middle, that was my first thought. But is this enough to justify this?

Answer (score 1):

We do b) in some detail, in the hope that will serve as a guide for c) and d).

We can work directly with $\hat{p}$, or with the sum of the $X_i$. I prefer to work with $\hat{p}$. This has mean $0.3$ and variance $\frac{p(1-p)}{100}$, so standard deviation $\sigma=\frac{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}{10}$. (This is not the same as the $\sigma$ in your post, which is the standard deviation of $X_1+\cdots+X_{100}$.)

We have
$$\Pr(0.25\le \hat{p}\le 0.35)=\Pr\left(-\frac{0.05}{\sigma}\le  \frac{\hat{p}-0.3}{\sigma}\le \frac{0.05}{\sigma}\right).$$
By the normal approximation, $\frac{\hat{p}-0.3}{\sigma}$ is roughly standard normal, so our required probability is approximately
$$\Pr\left(-\frac{0.05}{\sigma}\le Z\le \frac{0.05}{\sigma}\right),$$
where $Z$ is standard normal. Now the rest can be computed using values of $\Phi(z)$ for appropriate $z$.

*Another way*: We want $\Pr(25\le X_1+\cdots +X_{100}\le 35)$. The random variable $W=X_1+\cdots +X_{100}$ has mean $30$ and variance $100p(1-p)$, so standard deviation $\sigma'=10\sqrt{p(1-p)}$. Now we use the same style of calculation as in the first solution.

You used this approach, which is fine. However, the top of your middle term should have been $X_1+\cdots+X_{100}-30$. The tops of the two sides should have been $25-30$ and $35-30$. The denominators $10\sqrt{p(1-p)}$ that you used are correct.

Comment: the denominator is wrong too then, because I get $\mathbb{P}(-0.109108945 \leq \hat{p} \leq 0.109108945)$ but I need 1.09. I am confused with the $\mu$ and $p$. What is $\mathbb{P}$ when $p$ is the probability?

Comment: @Kiki: In the first approach I used, the standard deviation $\sqrt{0.21}/10$ is about $0.045825$. Dividing $0.05$ by this we get about $1.0911$. The probability that $Z$ is between $-1.0911$ and $1.0911$ is (tables) about $0.8621-0.1179$, that is, $0.7442$. The second way of doing it was essentially the same, numerators and denominators get multiplied by $100$. The resulting probability is the same.

Comment: To be more precise, in the second way the standard deviation is $10\sqrt{0.21}$, about $4.3825$. Dividing $-5$ by this we get $-1.0911$.